# how to change unique values within a specific column in a file to another value in linux?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this:

```
 col1 col2 col3
  1 1 1
  2 1 2
  3 1 1
  23 2 2
  2 1 1
  3 2 2
  2 2 2
```

I want in the second colum all the rows with value 1 be changed into 4. so output should be:

```
 col1 col2 col3
  1 4 1
  2 4 2
  3 4 1
  23 2 2
  2 4 1
  3 2 2
  2 2 2
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `awk` ternary operator for that,

```
awk '{$2=(($2=="1")?"4":$2)}1' file
```

Since by *default* `awk` splits input fields by a single white-space, we can directly check `$2` to contain value as `1` if so we can replace it as `4` else keep the value itself. The `{}1` will print the file with the updates to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at awk.

Try, for example, the following:

`cat your_file_name | awk {'printf $1 " " (($2!="1") ? $2 : "4") " " $3 "\n";'}`